# Referring a friend

Tags: professionalism

I have a friend I am going to refer for an opening at my company.

I have a good relationship with the management of the department with the opening. When submitting the referral form to HR, should I CC those managers or is that inappropriate?

The person in HR who I am submitting to has a good relationship with me as well, she took me on board as an intern which started my career.

Answer (score 7):

> When submitting the referral form to HR, should I CC those managers or
>   is that inappropriate?

Ask your friend in HR.

I'm guessing HR has a process to funnel referrals to the relevant department and thus CCing them will be unnecessary (and perhaps inappropriate), but HR will be able to guide you.

Answer (score 2):

It might be an idea to speak with your manager before referring to HR.

I feel that it'll be better to make sure that your friend is a good fit for the role being applied for before taking the time to go through the application and HR interviews.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't CC the prospective managers on the mail to HR, it muddies the waters slighty. HR may misinterpret and assume it's a referral that is *supported* by these managers for example.

What I would do however is give the departmental managers a heads up after sending it. Either verbally if you work close by or even simply forwarding the e-mail on to them afterwards with a short note explaining that this is a referral for their department that you've passed to HR and you're keeping them in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

HR is the door into the company.Won't do any good by CCing prospective managers.
However, a verbal headsup/ putting good word about your friend to the managers will definitely increase his/her chances.